# Asynchronous client/server using java jeromq

Tags: java, zeromq, jeromq

I am using `0.4.0` version of `jeromq` and I was trying to use below example from this [link](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:asyncsrv) but it is giving compilation error on this line `ZMQ.poll(items, 10);`. It looks like something has changed in the recent version of `jeromq` but the documentation and code is not updated yet. Can anyone help me understand how can I adapt my below code to use with latest version of `jeromq`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zeromq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jeromq</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the code:

```
public class asyncsrv {
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  // This is our client task
  // It connects to the server, and then sends a request once per second
  // It collects responses as they arrive, and it prints them out. We will
  // run several client tasks in parallel, each with a different random ID.
  private static Random rand = new Random(System.nanoTime());

  private static class client_task implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
      ZContext ctx = new ZContext();
      Socket client = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.DEALER);

      // Set random identity to make tracing easier
      String identity = String.format("%04X-%04X", rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt());
      client.setIdentity(identity.getBytes());
      client.connect("tcp://localhost:5570");

      PollItem[] items = new PollItem[] {new PollItem(client, Poller.POLLIN)};

      int requestNbr = 0;
      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        // Tick once per second, pulling in arriving messages
        for (int centitick = 0; centitick < 100; centitick++) {
          // this line is giving compilation error as it says undefined
          ZMQ.poll(items, 10);
          if (items[0].isReadable()) {
            ZMsg msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(client);
            msg.getLast().print(identity);
            msg.destroy();
          }
        }
        client.send(String.format("request #%d", ++requestNbr), 0);
      }
      ctx.destroy();
    }
  }

  // This is our server task.
  // It uses the multithreaded server model to deal requests out to a pool
  // of workers and route replies back to clients. One worker can handle
  // one request at a time but one client can talk to multiple workers at
  // once.
  private static class server_task implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
      ZContext ctx = new ZContext();

      // Frontend socket talks to clients over TCP
      Socket frontend = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
      frontend.bind("tcp://*:5570");

      // Backend socket talks to workers over inproc
      Socket backend = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.DEALER);
      backend.bind("inproc://backend");

      // Launch pool of worker threads, precise number is not critical
      for (int threadNbr = 0; threadNbr < 5; threadNbr++)
        new Thread(new server_worker(ctx)).start();

      // Connect backend to frontend via a proxy
      ZMQ.proxy(frontend, backend, null);

      ctx.destroy();
    }
  }

  // Each worker task works on one request at a time and sends a random number
  // of replies back, with random delays between replies:

  private static class server_worker implements Runnable {
    private ZContext ctx;

    public server_worker(ZContext ctx) {
      this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public void run() {
      Socket worker = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.DEALER);
      worker.connect("inproc://backend");

      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        // The DEALER socket gives us the address envelope and message
        ZMsg msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(worker);
        ZFrame address = msg.pop();
        ZFrame content = msg.pop();
        assert (content != null);
        msg.destroy();

        // Send 0..4 replies back
        int replies = rand.nextInt(5);
        for (int reply = 0; reply < replies; reply++) {
          // Sleep for some fraction of a second
          try {
            Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(1000) + 1);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          }
          address.send(worker, ZFrame.REUSE + ZFrame.MORE);
          content.send(worker, ZFrame.REUSE);
        }
        address.destroy();
        content.destroy();
      }
      ctx.destroy();
    }
  }

  // The main thread simply starts several clients, and a server, and then
  // waits for the server to finish.

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ZContext ctx = new ZContext();
    new Thread(new client_task()).start();
    new Thread(new client_task()).start();
    new Thread(new client_task()).start();
    new Thread(new server_task()).start();

    // Run for 5 seconds then quit
    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    ctx.destroy();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In 0.4.0 there is no poll method. But you can use `ZPoller` instead.

Example:

**1** - You need to new instance of poller:

```
ZPoller zPoller = new ZPoller(ctx);
zPoller.register(client, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
```

**2** - poll:

```
zPoller.poll(10);
```

**3** - and read if socket is readable:

```
if (zPoller.isReadable(client)) {
    ZMsg msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(client);
    msg.getLast().print(identity);
    msg.destroy();
}
```

So you code will look like this:

```
public class asyncsrv {
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // This is our client task
    // It connects to the server, and then sends a request once per second
    // It collects responses as they arrive, and it prints them out. We will
    // run several client tasks in parallel, each with a different random ID.
    private static Random rand = new Random(System.nanoTime());

    private static class client_task implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            ZContext ctx = new ZContext();
            ZMQ.Socket client = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.DEALER);

            // Set random identity to make tracing easier
            String identity = String.format("%04X-%04X", rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt());
            client.setIdentity(identity.getBytes());
            client.connect("tcp://localhost:5570");

            //ZMQ.PollItem[] items = new ZMQ.PollItem[] {new ZMQ.PollItem(client, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN)};
            ZPoller zPoller = new ZPoller(ctx);
            zPoller.register(client, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);

            int requestNbr = 0;
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // Tick once per second, pulling in arriving messages
                for (int centitick = 0; centitick < 100; centitick++) {
                    // this line is giving compilation error as it says undefined
                    //ZMQ.poll(items, 10);
                    zPoller.poll(10);
                    /*if (items[0].isReadable()) {
                        ZMsg msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(client);
                        msg.getLast().print(identity);
                        msg.destroy();
                    }*/
                    if (zPoller.isReadable(client)) {
                        ZMsg msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(client);
                        msg.getLast().print(identity);
                        msg.destroy();
                    }
                }
                client.send(String.format("request #%d", ++requestNbr), 0);
            }
            ctx.destroy();
        }
    }

    // This is our server task.
    // It uses the multithreaded server model to deal requests out to a pool
    // of workers and route replies back to clients. One worker can handle
    // one request at a time but one client can talk to multiple workers at
    // once.
    private static class server_task implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            ZContext ctx = new ZContext();

            // Frontend socket talks to clients over TCP
            ZMQ.Socket frontend = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
            frontend.bind("tcp://*:5570");

            // Backend socket talks to workers over inproc
            ZMQ.Socket backend = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.DEALER);
            backend.bind("inproc://backend");

            // Launch pool of worker threads, precise number is not critical
            for (int threadNbr = 0; threadNbr < 5; threadNbr++)
                new Thread(new server_worker(ctx)).start();

            // Connect backend to frontend via a proxy
            ZMQ.proxy(frontend, backend, null);

            ctx.destroy();
        }
    }

    // Each worker task works on one request at a time and sends a random number
    // of replies back, with random delays between replies:

    private static class server_worker implements Runnable {
        private ZContext ctx;

        public server_worker(ZContext ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        public void run() {
            ZMQ.Socket worker = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.DEALER);
            worker.connect("inproc://backend");

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // The DEALER socket gives us the address envelope and message
                ZMsg msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(worker);
                ZFrame address = msg.pop();
                ZFrame content = msg.pop();
                assert (content != null);
                msg.destroy();

                // Send 0..4 replies back
                int replies = rand.nextInt(5);
                for (int reply = 0; reply < replies; reply++) {
                    // Sleep for some fraction of a second
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(1000) + 1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    address.send(worker, ZFrame.REUSE + ZFrame.MORE);
                    content.send(worker, ZFrame.REUSE);
                }
                address.destroy();
                content.destroy();
            }
            ctx.destroy();
        }
    }

    // The main thread simply starts several clients, and a server, and then
    // waits for the server to finish.

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ZContext ctx = new ZContext();
        new Thread(new client_task()).start();
        new Thread(new client_task()).start();
        new Thread(new client_task()).start();
        new Thread(new server_task()).start();

        // Run for 5 seconds then quit
        Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
        ctx.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: got it now.. Also what is the difference between `close` and `destroy`. Should I call `close` on `zPoller` or `destroy`?

Comment: @user1234 close method doesn't handles IOException and destroy does (it calls close method actually). also, this is pretty funny, but both these methods are useless, cause we don't have any selectors here))